# Define a macro variable for the quarter number

Tags: macros, sas

*Part A:*

Define a macro variable for the quarter number. The idea is that this is the only thing the "user" should have to change when running the program for a new quarter.

*Part B:*

Define macro variables for each month in the quarter and set them equal to a month value that is generated from the quarter number. Hint: `%if/%then`

Given code:

```
data Month1;
input Name $ sales;
cards;
    Joyce 235
    Marsha 352
    Bill 491
    Vernon 210
    Sally 418
    ;
data Month2;
input Name $ sales;
cards;
Joyce 169
Marsha 281
Bill 315
Vernon 397
Sally 305
;
data Month3;
input Name $ sales;
cards;
Joyce 471
Marsha 314
Bill 394
Vernon 291
Sally 337
;
data Month4;
input Name $ sales;
cards;
Joyce 338
Marsha 259
Bill 310
Vernon 432
Sally 362
;
data Month5;
input Name $ sales;
cards;
Joyce 209
Marsha 355
Bill 302
Vernon 416
Sally 475
;
data Month6;
input Name $ sales;
cards;
Joyce 306
Marsha 472
Bill 351
Vernon 405
Sally 358
;
proc sql;
create table qtr1 as
select Month1.name, month1.sales as m1sales, month2.sales as m2sales,
  month3.sales as m3sales, sum(month1.sales, month2.sales, month3.sales) as qtr1sales
  from month1, month2, month3
  where month1.name=month2.name=month3.name;
select sum(m1sales) as m1total, sum(m2sales) as m2total, sum(m3sales) as m3total,
  sum(qtr1sales) as qtr1total
  from qtr1;
```

*My solution:*

```
/* question a */
%MACRO qtrn(qtr);

proc print data=&qtr ;
run;

%MEND qtrn;

/* question b */
%Macro Firstqtr(qtr);
     %Let I = 1;
    %If &qtr = qtr1 %then %do %until (&I > 3);
        %Let var&I = Month&I;
        %let I = %eval(&I + 1);
        %end;
%Mend Firstqtr;
%Firstqtr(qtr);
```

Can anyone help me figure correct solution?

Comment: How about adding date variable to data? (date_var=mdy(&month,'01',2017); Then you can group quarter by Quarter=qtf(date_var).

Comment: I am not supposed to change or modify data

Comment: Drop the variable after using it. No-one will ever know? :)

Comment: can you give me some hint, I am unable to understand, how to do that

Comment: You're overthinking this. The answer to one should be a single line of code. For the month use the INTNX function inside a data _null_ step to create the macro variables rather than mess about with macros and %sysfunc()

Comment: And the first part of you 'code' has absolutely no relevance to the question you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since this looks like a homework problem, here's the main part of your answer.  I'll leave the final select for you to add.  Should be pretty simple given the following solution:

```
%macro qtrSales(qtr);   
    %do i = 1 %to 3;
       %let month&i = month%sysevalf((&qtr-1) * 3 + &i);
       %put &&month&i;
    %end;

    proc sql;
         create table qtr&qtr as
                select &month1..name, 
                       &month1..sales as &month1.sales, 
                       &month2..sales as &month2.sales,
                       &month3..sales as &month3.sales, 
                       sum(&month1..sales, &month2..sales, &month3..sales) as qtr&qtr.sales
                from &month1, &month2, &month3
                     where &month1..name=&month2..name=&month3..name;

                select sum(&month1.sales) as &month1.total, 
                       sum(&month2.sales) as &month2.total, 
                       sum(&month3.sales) as &month3.total,
                       sum(qtr&qtr.sales) as qtr&qtr.total
                from qtr&qtr; 

               select sum(&month1.sales) as &month1.total, 
                      sum(&month2.sales) as &month2.total, 
                      sum(&month3.sales) as &month3.total,
                      sum(qtr&qtr.sales) as qtr&qtr.total
                      from qtr&qtr;
               quit;


%mend qtrSales;
%qtrSales(2);
```

Comment: i've updated the answer, please accept by checking the checkmark.  If you don't understand what's going on ask specific questions about the code.  It's not that complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`define a macro variable` means simply to use `%let` to define a macro variable.  `macro variables` are things that you define with `%let`, `call symputx`, or `select into` in SQL, and then reference using `&`.

```
%let qtrn = 3;
```

There you go.  The question specified that the user will adjust this, right?  So it isn't asking you to do any work on your end, just give the user a place to make this change.

As for the second, I don't entirely understand the hint.  It doesn't seem necessary to use conditional logic here.  Here's an example of what I'd do.

```
%let month1 = %eval(3*(&qtrn.-1)+1);
```

That simply calculates the month number of the first month based on the quarter.  Quarter 3 is months 7/8/9, right?  3*(3-1)+1 = 7, 3*(3-1)+2 = 8, 3*(3-1)+2 = 9.  (Or you could do it differently, 3*3-2 = 7, 3*3-1 = 8, 3*3 = 9)

Of course, you could do this in a macro with a loop to define them.  But it seems excessive to do so - it's not like quarters ever have 4 months in them, or 2, right?  They always have 3, it's a defining characteristic of a quarter, so it seems fine to hardcode month1/month2/month3.